# What's the difference between && and || in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, logical-operators

Here's a perfect illustration I saw.

&&

```
if (num > 5 && num < 10) {
return "Yes";
}
return "No";
```

||

```
if (num > 10 || num < 5) {
return "No";
}
return "Yes";
```

What's the difference between these two?

Comment: || - any condition true - true. && all conditions true- true.

Comment: And & Or. Basic operators.

Comment: Hmms, basic stuff. There are multiple answers to this on this website, such as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41176040/javascript-logical-operators-and-vs-or. But nonetheless welcome at SO. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators).

Comment: var num = 6;

if (num > 5 && num++ < 10) {
 // do something
} 
console.log(num);



var num = 6;

if (num < 10 || num++ < 5) {
 // do something
} 
console.log(num); - As said by everyone they are the basic and & or operators. However, copy this and see a difference

Answer (score 0):

They are AND (&&) and OR (||) operators.

In your first example the response will only be "Yes" if `num` is greater than 5 AND less than 10, so any value for `num` between 5 and 10 (exclusively) will return "Yes".

In your second example "No" will be returned if `num` is greater than 10 OR less then 5, so any value between 5 and 10 (inclusively) will return "Yes".

Comment: I can think of a number that is greater than 5 AND less than 10.

Comment: Check the edit - I misread the first example. My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

To make the expression

```
num > 5 && num < 10
```

negative,

```
!(num > 5 && num < 10)
```

you need to apply [De Morgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

```
!(num > 5) || !(num < 10)
```

and reverse the condition inside of the parens

```
num <= 5 || num >= 10
```

In your question you have the expression with logical Or `||`

```
num > 10 || num < 5
```

which is, despite the order, obviously not the same as the above expression. The result of comparing values is not the same.